# Hibernate a column prefix for table

Tags: java, hibernate, prefix

I got an existing database in which each table has its own column prefix. This means that every column in a tbale starts with the same 5 characters. For example `exec_` or `opos_`. Now I want to start using hibernate as ORM for this database and the POJOs.

My problem is, that the code which I got with the database, has an abstract class which is extended by 3 different POJOs. This means I have 3 tables with 3 different prefixes but a bunch of common columns (which all start with different prefixes, depending on the table). This stops me from just defining the `@Column(name = <col_name>)` for each field.

My question is, is there a way to define this prefix for each table to be prepended automatically or what option do I have to use?

Comment: Annotations are static, and thus it's probably not possible using plain java/spring, to do that.

Comment: The prefix is static for each table. I would add the annotation to the POJOs which extend the super class. This means if I access POJO A, then prefix A will be prepended to the mapped superclass columns. If I access POJO B, then prefix B will be prepended to the mapped superclass columns

Comment: I think `@AttributeOverride` would also be a way, but for 20+ columns in the superclass it would be pretty inconvenient

Comment: inheritance doesn't work very good with static things. In your case annotations. Its similar to defining a `static` variable in your superclass and then every subclass changes the value of said variable. What will be chosen at the end? I am sorry, but without any additional generation tool i think that its not possible

Comment: It is not about inheritance. Its simply about prepending some value in front of the columns names. If its more understandable for you, then you can ignore the part about the superclass